# Unable to upgrade PHP 7.1 to 7.2 in Mac

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have used below commands to upgrade php in my mac machine.

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew unlink php71
brew install php72 --with-argon2 
brew install php72-xdebug
```

PHP 7.2 has been successfully installed. I have checked with the command `php -v` and getting the version PHP 7.1 in my terminal. Please help.

Comment: Have you restarted you terminal or PC?

Comment: Is the program `php` symlinked to `php72`? What is the output for `php72 -v`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your comments, php7.2 successfully installed and only issue with your /usr/bin/php symlink. Please do the following steps.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

append the below line

```
alias php="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php"
```

save and exit `.bash_profile` then run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can run php7.2 in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl to update php version.

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

Last Step:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

brew unlink php71 and brew link php72 will tweak your php command line to the right path and version, but Apache will not be affected until you change its config file.

First, locate your httpd.conf file path:

```
httpd -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

You may also check:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Then:

Open your `httpd.conf` file and locate the line starting with LoadModule
php Comment this line with #, and add your 7.2 line instead.

You can get your line from querying the following command in the Terminal:

```
brew info php@7.2 | grep LoadModule it should look like: LoadModule
php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.
```

so Finally, restart Apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart your script should now
```

be runing with php7.2 version There's also detailed instructions about
using a php switcher here. Once installed, you can switch from one
version to another like this (it will link both Apache and the command
line automatically):

sphp 7.1

sphp 7.2

sphp 5.6

etc..